# Laravel Job Queue not processing using Redis driver

Tags: php, laravel, redis, publish-subscribe

I'm creating a job, pushing it on to a custom queue, and trying to use the Redis driver to then handle the job when it hits the queue, without success:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public function method() {
        $job = (new UpdateLiveThreadJob())->onQueue('live');
        $this->dispatch($job);
    }
}
```

Here is my queue config:

```
    'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER'),

    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue'  => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
```

Here is my `.env` file:

```
# Drivers (Queues & Broadcasts)
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
```

Here's my job:

```
class UpdateLiveThreadJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Rerender content
        $templatedOutput = view('templates.livethreadcontents')->with([
            'updates' => collect(Redis::lrange('live:updates', 0, -1))->reverse()->map(function($update) {
                return json_decode($update);
            })
        ])->render();

        // Connect to external service

        // Update Thread
    }
}
```

Indeed, I can change the `handle` method to do nothing to ensure it's nothing in the job that's actually causing it to fail, and it still doesn't process:

```
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        print_r('test');
    }
```

Using Redis, I can see it's pushed onto the queue:

```
> lrange queues:live 0 -1
> // json encoded job present
> llen queues:live
> // shows there is a job in the queue
```

Yet, it never actually fires, to my knowledge. Watching `php artisan queue:listen` shows nothing (only unrelated event broadcasts). What's going on here?

Answer (score 14):

With Laravel 5.3 there were changes to queues. Now you would run `php artisan queue:work --queue=live` and that should do what you need.

I’ve left my original answer below.

---

Are you remembering to run `php artisan queue:listen --queue=live`?

You need to define the queue name when running the listen command otherwise you end up only listening to the `default` queue.

If you want to run multiple queues and managing things in production you can use something like [Upstart](https://serversforhackers.com/video/process-monitoring-with-upstart) (not directly related to setting up Laravel queues, but provides a good starting point) or [Supervisor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration) to manage the processes. Both of these are available on Forge and Homestead.

Finally assuming you are on Laravel 5 you may want to consider running `php artisan queue:work --daemon --queue=live` as this reduces the CPU overhead of running the worker as it doesn't reload the framework with each job. But you must remember to restart the worker when you deploy new code for your jobs otherwise things won't be picked up.

Comment: Wait, really? I can't believe it's this simple! I have never been told or shown this, and the documentation doesn't imply it. How can I run all queues? Is there some sort of `*` attribute I can provide?

Comment: Unfortunately as far as I'm aware it's only a single queue listener rather than listening to all available queues, there's not really an API that suggests Laravel has an awareness of all possible queues. 

I've just run a worker for each queue name then I can adjust things like retries, and time to execute on a per-queue basis.

Comment: Just added a few more notes about how to automate starting the queues, should make it a bit easier. Not quite the wildcard you are looking for but should help you get a bit closer.

Comment: Hi Marcus, so I've set my `supervisord` instance to run: `command=php /home/vagrant/myproj/artisan queue:work redis --queue=default,live,email,uploads --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon`, but still, only the events and jobs on the `default` queue are being run, now, jobs which should go on the `live` queue aren't even being queued (even less helpful than before). What's going on here?

Comment: I think you can only name a single queue in the queue argument

Comment: This took hours of my life i cant get back. Thanks!

Comment: the ``--daemon`` parameter is DEPRECATED

Comment: @YassineMokni thanks for the heads up. It’s been a while since I’ve used Laravel. I’ve updated my answer for any passers by.